# New Web Site or MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

I have a website that primarily renders pages from a database.  We also have a user management system in the website, requiring login, profile management, credit card processing, etc.  There are some places in the site that have application functionality, like a forum, but most of the site is dynamic content, rendering from a the database.  Content is entered with an inhouse CMS that is not tied to the website.

I'm upgrading the website from ASP to .Net 4.5 framework.  What is the best option for this new project in VS 2012?  An ASP.Net MVC 4 Application (Internet Application) or a new ASP.Net Web Site (Razor v2)?

I'm leaning towards ASP.Net MVC 4 Application (Internet Application, Razor), instead of Web site.

**UPDATE:**  I've actually done a lot of reading on this, whether here in SO, or other sites, and still am not sure which is the best option for migrating to .Net from classic ASP for my specific needs.

Current:

1. Classic ASP website (100's of pages), public facing.
2. Most pages are rendered from a database, with template HTML in .asp page, when data populated from database.  Could be compared to a WordPress site in function.  Content is entered into CMS, and rendered on the website via templates.
3. Members log in to the site, have profiles, make payments, and more.
4. Have a forum
5. All URLs designed for search engines.  URL Rewriting in IIS.  I need to keep the existing URLs, and have them work with the new .Net site.  IMPORTANT.
6. Client side operations are a must, integrating with jQuery tools, lightbox, etc.
7. This is not an "application" website, per say.   It is a public facing website, like MSNBC or similar, that gets updated frequently (several times per month, if not more).

I'm at a loss for choosing the ideal project type for this migration to .Net.  I don't think web forms are a good choice, and MVC 4 appears to be a good choice based on what I've read, but perhaps I can do everything that is necessary with a standard ASP.Net Website (Razor v2) template.

I'd like to get some opinions on which way to go with this, from people that have done it already.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for posting the wrong type of question.  Based on other questions I read on SO similar to this, it seemed reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use .NET MVC 4 . But there is not much online source if you get stuck. But I think you will survive anyway. The only downside is that you need more time to learn the new stuff because it is very different from the old stuff.

If you have enough time, go with the MVC 4. Once you do the project with it, you can do any changes easily in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Borsel.  I agree, and have no problem working with MVC 4.  One other thing, referencing another question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174425/upgrade-classic-asp-to-mvc-4-0,  do you think it will be difficult to maintain existing URLs when moving to MVC 4?

Comment: I answered that question too. I hope it explains what you need and get marked

Comment: I've elaborated on the question here.  I'm still not sure which is best for my situation.  Based on what I've read, many say MVC 4 (Razor).  But, it's hard to determine if that is best for me, or over-complicates things (the current site is not that complex), based on the type of site I have, and requirements.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

There are three kinds of websites you can create out of the box (and a number of subtypes).  ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET Web Pages, and ASP.NET MVC.  Which one you choose is as much a matter of personal preference as it is anything else, although certain kinds of sites make certain things easier to do.

In general (and these are not hard and fast rules)

WebForms - This is the way that 90% of the people do it, and there is lots of knowledge and books and information out there.  It works, but has a lot of things you have to deal with in terms of creating standard conforming html, testability and maintainability.  There are solutions to all these problems, and they're well known, but in general it's considered "old technology" (not as old as classic asp though)

WebPages - This technology is based on the Razor view engine, and treats pages more like classic ASP where you intermix code and html.  In general, this allows you to quickly create web sites with functionality behind them, but at the cost of longer term maintainability and testability.  As with anything, you could force process to solve these problems, but the framework itself is not really geared towards it.

MVC - This technology is based on the well known and well understood MVC user interface pattern.  It focuses on separation of concerns to improve maintainability, testability, and ease of development.  It does require a significant departure from traditional ASP.NET development, and a steep learning curve.  You have to know HTML, CSS and JavaScript in much more depth than with WebForms.

I use MVC for everything I can, it's just more logical for me.  MVC is one of those things that is really confusing until you reach an "ah hah!" moment, then it all snaps into place.

What you choose is entirely up to you.  You have to decide HOW you want to develop, and that will guide your decision.

Comment: Thanks.  Would MVC with Razor (which is the default in VS2012 for MVC 4 Web Application) then be a combination of WebPages and MVC?  I think MVC is the way to go.  I am struggling with whether this is reasonable with the requirements.  Like, maintaining all the current URLs.  I can use custom routing for this, but does this over-complicate things with MVC, and it would make more sense to just go with WebPages (Razor)?  I understand that you're just sharing opinions, but they are valuable.

Comment: @devnuts - no, in MVC Razor is used as a templating engine (MVC calls them ViewEngines).  You can put code in them like you would in WebPages, but this is discouraged except for strictly presentational related logic.  In WebPages you have business logic in your razor code, in MVC you don't.

Comment: Are you saying MVC Razor is NOT a good choice for what I have decribed?  I've read good things about Razor, but have not used it enough to make a good decision on moving forward with it in this upgrade.

Comment: @devnuts - No, i'm not saying that at all.  I have no idea where you got that from, I simply answered your question.

Comment: OK, "but this is discouraged except for strictly presentational related logic", is what I was questioning. I see what you mean now though.  Thanks.

Comment: @devnuts - It's discouraged to write code as you would in WebPages when using Razor in MVC.  The point is that MVC and WebPages use Razor differently.  in WebPages all your code goes in the page (well, not all.. you can call classes and methods from other objects) while in MVC that code goes in the controller, and not in the razor code.